# Is this the correct way to map finite differences from the radial to the exponential coordinate system?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, coordinate-systems, finite-differences

I am currently numerically solving the following partial differential equation using finite differences:

$$ C  {\partial ^2v \over \partial t^2} = 
{\partial ^2v \over \partial r^2} +
{ 1\over r}{\partial v \over \partial r} -
{ 1\over r^2} v +
(2C^2-1){\partial ^2v \over \partial z^2}
\tag 1$$

with the boundary condition:

$$ {\partial v \over \partial r} \Bigg |_{r=1} =
{2C^2-1 \over2(C^2-1)}f 
\tag 2$$

where $C$ is a constant and both $v$ and $f$ are functions of $r$, $z$ and $t$. I am having stability issues at the radial boundary, so I wanted to try out coordinate transformation to see if I might get a more stable result. However, I don't quite understand how to do that transformation, so I am hoping someone here can help me with that.

I used the following radial to exponential coordinate transformation:

$$ x = \ln (r)                 \tag 3$$
$$ e^x = r                     \tag 4$$
$$ e^{-x} = {1 \over r}        \tag 5$$
$$ {dx \over dr} = {1 \over r} \tag 6$$
$$ {dx \over dr} = e^{-x}      \tag 7$$

Using the chain rule I derived:

$$ {\partial v \over \partial r} = 
e^{-x}{\partial v \over \partial x} \tag 8$$

$$ {\partial ^2 v \over \partial r^2} = e^{-2x}\Bigg(
{\partial ^2 v \over \partial x^2}
-{\partial v \over \partial x} \Bigg) \tag 9$$

This transformed equation $(1)$ and the boundary condition $(2)$ into:

$$ C \cdot {\partial ^2v \over \partial t^2} = e^{-2x} \Bigg(
{\partial ^2 v \over \partial x^2} -
{v} \Bigg) +
(2C^2-1){\partial ^2v \over \partial z^2}
\tag {10} $$

$$ {\partial v \over \partial x} \Bigg |_{x=0} =
{2C^2-1 \over2(C^2-1)}f 
\tag {11}$$

From Taylor's expansion, we get:

$$ v(r + h_r) = v(r) + 
h_r {\partial v(r) \over \partial r} +
{1 \over 2} (h_r)^2 {\partial ^2 v(r) \over \partial r^2} 
\tag {12}$$

$$ v(r - h_l) = v(r) - 
h_l {\partial v(r) \over \partial r} +
{1 \over 2} (h_l)^2 {\partial ^2 v(r) \over \partial r^2} 
\tag {13}$$

where $h_r = (r + \Delta r) - r$ and $h_l = r - (r - \Delta r)$. When we subtract equation $(13)$ from $(12)$ we get the central difference expression:

$$ {\partial v(r) \over \partial r} =
{ v(r + h_r) - v(r - h_l) \over h_r + h_l} \tag {14}$$

Similarly, adding $(13)$ and $(12)$ yields the central difference expression:

$$ {\partial ^2 v(r) \over \partial r^2} =
{ v(r + h_r) + v(r - h_l) - 2v(r) \over 
{1 \over 2}((h_r)^2 + (h_l)^2)} \tag {15}$$

Because $h_r = h_l$, expressions $(14)$ and $(15)$ can be simplified to:

$$ {\partial v(r) \over \partial r} =
{ v(r + \Delta r) - v(r - \Delta r) \over 2 \Delta r} \tag {16}$$

$$ {\partial ^2 v(r) \over \partial r^2} =
{ v(r + \Delta r) + v(r - \Delta r) - 2v(r) \over 
\Delta r^2} \tag {17}$$

Here is where I get confused. The value of $\Delta r = r(j+1)-r(j)=r(j)-r(j-1)$ is constant since I am using an evenly spaced grid for the radial coordinate system (note that $j$ is the grid point index). However, it seems that $\Delta x$ is actually not constant. Here is what I mean.

I want to calculate the left $\Delta x$ and right $\Delta x$. Note that:

$$x(j-1) = \ln \Big( r(j-1) \Big) \tag {18}$$
$$x(j)   = \ln \Big( r(j)   \Big) \tag {19}$$
$$x(j+1) = \ln \Big( r(j+1) \Big) \tag {20}$$

If I calculate it from the left I get:

$$ \Delta x = x(j) - x(j - 1) \tag {21}$$
$$ \Delta x = \ln \Big( r(j  ) \Big) - 
              \ln \Big( r(j-1) \Big) \tag {22}$$
$$ \Delta x = \ln \Big( r(j  ) \Big) - 
              \ln \Big( r(j) - \Delta r \Big) \tag {23}$$
$$ \Delta x = \ln \Bigg( {r(j) \over r(j) - \Delta r} \Bigg) = d_l \tag {24}$$

But if I calculate it from the right I get:

$$ \Delta x = x(j + 1) - x(j) \tag {25}$$
$$ \Delta x = \ln \Big( r(j + 1) \Big) - 
              \ln \Big( r(j) \Big) \tag {26}$$
$$ \Delta x = \ln \Big( r(j) + \Delta r \Big) - 
              \ln \Big( r(j)\Big) \tag {27}$$
$$ \Delta x = \ln \Bigg( {r(j)  + \Delta r \over r(j)} \Bigg)  = d_r\tag {28}$$

So it appears that $d_l$ and $d_r$ are not equal! Does this mean I can not use the following central difference approximations at the boundary:

$$ {\partial v(x) \over \partial x} =
{ v(x + \Delta x) - v(x - \Delta x) \over 2 \Delta x} \tag {29}$$

$$ {\partial ^2 v(x) \over \partial x^2} =
{ v(x + \Delta x) + v(x - \Delta x) - 2v(x) \over 
\Delta x^2} \tag {30}$$

and that I should instead use:

$$ {\partial v(x) \over \partial x} =
{ v(x + d_r) - v(x - d_l) \over d_r + d_l} \tag {31}$$

$$ {\partial ^2 v(x) \over \partial x^2} =
{ v(x + d_r) + v(x - d_l) - 2v(x) \over 
{1 \over 2}((d_r)^2 + (d_l)^2)} \tag {32}$$

Also, am I right to assume the following statements are correct:

$$ v(x + d_l) = v(r + h_l) \tag {33} $$
$$ v(x)       = v(r)       \tag {34} $$
$$ v(x + d_r) = v(r + h_r) \tag {35} $$

In summary, I am confused if I should use expressions $(29)$ and $(30)$ or $(31)$ and $(32)$ to approximate the partial derivatives at the boundary of my problem and I'm also not sure if the statements $(33)$, $(34)$ and $(35)$ are correct. An answer with an explanation would be of great help to me.

Comment: You either shift the stencil from a uniform-$r$ grid to a uniform $x$-grid, or you change the weights in computing the derivative, in order to achieve $O(\lVert (\Delta r_j)_j\rVert^2)$ local truncation error of your scheme.

Comment: A uniform x-grid stencil requires me to use the exponential coordinate system right from the start of the algorithm. But I can't because  $x$ tends to $- \infty $ when $r$ is equal to zero. I also have the Neumann boundary condition at $r=0$. Changing the weights would mean using more terms of the Taylor series, right? That requires me to know additional boundary conditions for the ghost nods, which I don't.